# How to pass a string as parameter in AWK within Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a text file which I want to filter
using awk. The text file looks like this:

```
foo 1
bar 2
bar 0.3
bar 100
qux 1033
```

I want to filter those files with awk inside a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

#input file
input=myfile.txt

# I need to pass this as parameter
# cos later I want to make it more general like
# coltype=$1
col1type="foo"   

#Filters
awk '$2>0 && $1==$col1type' $input
```

But somehow it failed. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need double quotes to allow variable interpolation, which means you then need to escape the other dollar signs with backslashes so `$1` and `$2` are *not* interpolated. Also you need double quotes around `"$col1type"`.

```
awk "\$2>0 && \$1==\"$col1type\""
```

Answer (score 11):

pass it in using `-v` option of `awk`. that way, you separate out awk variables and shell variables. Its neater also without extra quoting.

```
#!/bin/bash

#input file
input=myfile.txt

# I need to pass this as parameter
# cos later I want to make it more general like
# coltype=$1
col1type="foo"   

#Filters
awk -vcoltype="$col1type" '$2>0 && $1==col1type' $input
```

Comment: The '-v' notation is POSIX compliant; older (System V-ish) versions of awk may also allow `parameter=value` without the '-v' option.  It is better to be explicit - use the '-v' unless there's a problem with it on your system.

Comment: If you do use the bare `parameter=value` syntax (without the `-v` prefix), it has to go between the `'$2>0 ...'` and the `$input` arguments. But I doubt there are many systems out there anymore that don't accept `-v`, and it is best to use it when possible. Also, this method is a bit more robust that John Kugelman's answer: what if coltype held the value `xyz{next} {print "garbage"}`?

Answer (score 6):

"double quote single quote"

```
awk '{print "'$1'"}'
```

example:

```
$./a.sh arg1 
arg1
```

```
$cat a.sh 
echo "test" | awk '{print "'$1'"}'
```

linux tested

Comment: Thanks! I'm kind of newbee, searching for hours how to simply import shell variable string to (a bit complex) awk expression.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes inhibit variable expansion in bash:

```
awk '$2>0 && $1=='"$col1type"
```