# How to pass string or variable as multiple parameters for awk within a bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, awk

I'm trying to pass a variable, `$formula` into an awk script:

```
[node2 filtering]$ echo $formula
$25 ~ "1/1" && $24 ~ "1/1" && $23 ~ "1/1" && $22 ~ "1/1" && $21 ~ "1/1" && $20 ~ "1/1" && $19 ~ "1/1" && $18 ~ "1/1" && $17 ~ "1/1" && $16 ~ "1/1" && $15 ~ "1/1" && $14 ~ "1/1" && $13 ~ "1/1" && $12 ~ "1/1" && $11 ~ "1/1" && $10 ~ "1/1"||$10 ~ "0/1" && $11 ~ "0/1" && $12 ~ "0/1" && $13 ~ "0/1" && $14 ~ "0/1" && $15 ~ "0/1" && $16 ~ "0/1" && $17 ~ "0/1" && $18 ~ "0/1" && $19 ~ "0/1" && $20 ~ "0/1" && $21 ~ "0/1" && $22 ~ "0/1" && $23 ~ "0/1" && $24 ~ "0/1" && $25 ~ "0/1"
```

I'm trying to pass into the following to filter my text file, but when I do no filtering happens. I don't get an error either.

```
awk -F\\t  -v myvar="$formula" 'myvar {print $0}' myfile
```

This works:

```
awk -F\\t '$10 ~ "0/1" + $11 ~ "0/1"+ $12 ~ "0/1"+ $13 ~ "0/1"+ $14 ~ "0/1"{print $0}' myflies
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is that I have a simple for loop, which creates `$formula` based on the number of columns I want to filter. The number of columns I decide to filter upon is simply based on the number of subjects in the experiment and will always be `$10` to `$(10+n)` where n is the number of subjects.

Any ideas or tips would be greatly appreciated as to how to solve this problem or construct my script in a different manner?

Here's the silly for loop to construct `$formula`:

```
blah1=$(echo "")
blah2=$(echo "")
for (( i=1; i <= $NUMBEROFSUBJECTS; i++ ))
    do
     l=$(echo $(( i + $minus )))``

    if [ $i == 1 ] ; then
             blah1=$(echo " \$$l ~ \"1/1\" ")
             blah2=$(echo " \$$l ~ \"0/1\" ")
    else
            inter1=$(echo " \$$l ~ \"1/1\" ")
            blah1=$(echo $inter1 + $blah1)

            inter2=$(echo " \$$l ~ \"0/1\" ")
            blah2=$(echo $blah2+$inter2)
    fi
done
formula=$(echo $blah1  " || " $blah2)`
```

Here's where I got the `awk -F\\t  -v myvar="$formula" 'myvar {print $0}'` idea from:

[Howto Pass A String as Parameter in AWK within Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451635/howto-pass-a-string-as-parameter-in-awk-within-bash-script)

edit:
Answer that worked for me ended up being:

```
 awk -F\\t "$formula"'{print $0}' myfile
```

Thanks so much everyone. Sorry it ended up being so simple.

Comment: Variables are for data, not code.

Comment: So would it be a parameter or an argument or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
formula="$blah1|$blah2"
...
awk "/$formula/ {...}"
```

So the proposal is to skip the variable definition and just rely on the shell substitution.

Comment: I'd limit the double quotes to just what is necessary for shell expansion, something like `"/$formula/"'{...}'`.

Comment: I keep getting: `awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^ unterminated string` when I try either @yacc or @chepner methods of `"/$formula/ {...}"` or `"/$formula/"'{...}'`. Any ideas?

Comment: `awk -F\\t  /"$blah1/"'{print $0}'  myfile`  or  `awk -F\\t  /"$blah1/{print $0}" myfile`   is the command line call. The contents of formula is up in the main question. @yacc

Comment: The unterminated string arrow points at where `$formula` and `{print $0}` meet

Comment: Getting rid of the slashed made it work for me.  `awk -F\\t  "$formula"'{print $0}' `.